# Compile cygwin1.dll from its source code

Tags: windows, dll, compilation, cygwin

I want to edit some code in cygwin1.dll for my project. So, I clone git repository from these two url:

1. https://github.com/mirror/newlib-cygwin.git
2. git://sourceware.org/git/newlib-cygwin.git

I've gcc, g++, make installed with cygwin and mingw-w64 (and also in WSL). But none of them generate DLL file. I also follow the commands `./configure` & `make`. Command generates only object files. Is it possible to compile cygwin1.dll from its source code?

Comment: Of course, it is possible.I would guess you are missing some tool. Run `make |& tee make.log` and see why is not compiling the cygwin1.dll

Comment: PS: repository #1 is a mirror of #2

Comment: yes to both. Also configure from a cygwin enviroment

Comment: full build log. It does not fit in the buffer of terminal. Look for cygwin0.dll and cygwin1.dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had two different problems.

- First, I followed the steps in [cygwin FAQ: How do I build Cygwin on my own?](https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.programming.building-cygwin). I forget to install `mingww64_x86_64-gcc-g++` package. So, I installed those with the following commands:

```
setup-x86_64.exe -q -P gcc-g++ -P make -P perl -P cocom -P gettext-devel -P libiconv-devel -P zlib-devel
setup-x86_64.exe -q -P mingw64-x86_64-gcc-core -P mingw64-i686-gcc-g++ -P mingw64-i686-zlib 
setup-x86_64.exe -q -P mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++ -P mingw64-x86_64-zlib
```

- Second, I logged the output from make command with `make |& tee make.log`. Thanks, @matzeri for the logging tip. Then I followed an error in `make.log` file as below:

```
../../.././winsup/cygwin/cygmagic: line 25: /usr/bin/awk: cannot
execute binary file: Exec format error
*** WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING ***
*** ../../.././winsup/cygwin/child_info.h: magic number for
CHILD_INFO_MAGIC changed old 0xc96f5e9U != new
```

Somehow, the `awk` (hard linked with `gawk`) does not work in cygwin. So I installed `awk` package with setup-x86_64.exe. And now I can easily compile cygwin.dll.